Replicate files older than X using mino bucket replication
Using minio, I would like to replicate all files that did not change for X days in a main "source" bucket to a different bucket.
My usecase (roughly) is:

users add, update and remove files (and maybe folders) via a tool that uses minio via the S3 API (the users do not know and do not need to know that it is minio handling the data)
at some point, for a given folder, the work is done and users will no longer change anything in that folder
"at some point" can be expressed in a certain number of days (i.e. users work for a certain number of days in/with a specific folder)
then I want to replicate the content to a different bucket
at some point (after X+some days), the main folder the users were working with will be deleted

The idea is to use the replication to "archive" the data before it is (manually) removed again from the "main" minio bucket. But I do not want to archive/synchronise the intermediate state of the user's work.
Can this be done with minio somehow?
I am aware of the following resources which unfortunately do not seem to explain how this could be done but to the best of my knowledge also do not state that it definitely cannot be done...

Bucket Replication
Configure One-Way Bucket Replication Using the MinIO Console

